# How to store data from a GHashTable to a struct in C

Tags: c, struct, glib

I'm trying to iterate over my hash table and store the key and value into an array of structures. I keep getting a segfault. I'm guessing is due to the pointer based struct.

I'm still confused when I should use pointers to structures, and array of structures.

Edit: Got it to work. See answer below.

Comment: So, basically, you're allocating memory, then assuming this memory is zeroed out - which it is not, by the way, so s->len can be absolutely anything - and then using the first element of your dynamically allocated array of structs as a sort of a counter to the array.

Comment: I do not see similar fashion allocating memory for `char *` pointers, hint: `strdup`.... ;)

Comment: @Esa Lakaniemi: so do I have to use a global counter as opposed to have it within my struct?

Comment: I have initialized the struct, though, still I'm not able to run it. Any ideas what else I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <glib.h>

typedef struct st { 
    char *key;
    char *str;
    int len;
} MyStruct;

int z = 0;
static void hash2struct (gpointer key, gpointer value, gpointer data) {
    MyStruct **s = data; 
    gchar *k = (gchar *) key;
    gchar *h = (gchar *) value;
    s[z]->key = strdup(k);
    s[z]->str =strdup(h);
    z++;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int i;

    GHashTable *hash = g_hash_table_new(g_str_hash, g_str_equal);

    g_hash_table_insert(hash, "Virginia", "Richmond");
    g_hash_table_insert(hash, "Texas", "Austin");
    g_hash_table_insert(hash, "Ohio", "Columbus");

    MyStruct **s = malloc(sizeof(MyStruct) * 3);
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        s[i] = malloc(sizeof(MyStruct)); 
    }
    g_hash_table_foreach(hash, hash2struct, s); 

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        printf("%s %s\n", s[i]->str, s[i]->key);

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        free(s[i]->str);
        free(s[i]->key);
        free(s[i]);
    }
    free(s);
    g_hash_table_destroy(hash);
    return 0;
}
```